# How to copy automatically the home address in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-search

How to  display the home addresses automatically directly to Google Maps (maps.google.com) and display it into search bar of Google Maps? This home addresses is from another website (UAT) with pure JAVASCRIPT? Please help me. I'm new in that PL, so I'm not familiar. Thank you

Example:

In another website there's a text field for home address and the address that inputted is:

```
345 Bury Village Oslo St. Bershka City, Switzerland
```

And I want to copy/displayed that whole home address in Google Maps and automatically search that address

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
function scanLapVerification() {
try {
    var forAlert = '';
    var el = getElement(document, "class", "workflowActivityDetailPanel", "");
    if (el && el.length > 0) {
        var eltr = getElement(el[0], "tag", "tr", "");
        if (eltr && eltr.length > 0) {
            //Read Contact and Permanent address
            var addresses = {
                CA: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, snumber: null, building: null, floor: null}
               ,PA: { province: null, municipality: null, barangay: null, zip: null, street: null, building: null, bnumber: null, floor: null}
            };
            var address_type = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < eltr.length; i++) {
                tr_text = eltr[i].innerText;
                if (tr_text.substr(0, "Contact address".length) == "Contact address") address_type = "CA";
                if (tr_text.substr(0, "Permanent address".length) == "Permanent address") address_type = "PA";
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Province".length) == "Province") {
                    addresses[address_type].province = tr_text.substr("Province".length, tr_text.length - "Province".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Province: '+ addresses[address_type].province + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Municipality".length) == "Municipality") {
                    addresses[address_type].municipality = tr_text.substr("Municipality".length, tr_text.length - "Municipality".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert +  'Municipality: '+ addresses[address_type].municipality + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Barangay".length) == "Barangay") {
                    addresses[address_type].barangay = tr_text.substr("Barangay".length, tr_text.length - "Barangay".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Barangay: ' + addresses[address_type].barangay + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "ZIP Code".length) == "ZIP Code") {
                    addresses[address_type].zip = tr_text.substr("Zip Code".length, tr_text.length - "ZIP Code".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'ZIP Code: ' + addresses[address_type].zip + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Street name".length) == "Street") {
                    addresses[address_type].street = tr_text.substr("Street name".length, tr_text.length - "Street".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Street name: ' + addresses[address_type].street + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Street number".length) == "Street number") {
                    addresses[address_type].snumber = tr_text.substr("Street number".length, tr_text.length - "Street number".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Street number: ' + addresses[address_type].snumber + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Building name".length) == "Building name") {
                    addresses[address_type].building = tr_text.substr("Building".length, tr_text.length - "Building name".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Building name: ' + addresses[address_type].building + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
                if (address_type && tr_text.substr(0, "Floor number".length) == "Floor number") {
                    addresses[address_type].floor = tr_text.substr("Zip".length, tr_text.length - "Floor number".length);
                    forAlert = forAlert + 'Floor number: ' + addresses[address_type].floor + ',' + address_type + ' > ';
                }
            }

 //Open a new tab for Google Maps
           In this place need to put the code for New tab
//Enter full address into search input
           In this place need to put the code for Displaying the Home Address from another website into Google Maps search bar automatically
        }
    }
    return { status: "KO" };
} catch (e) {
        alert("Exception: scanLapVerification\n" + e.Description);
    return { status: "KO", message: e };
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/JkLSC/2/)
You need to use [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
Like that:

**HTML**

```
<input id="address" value="Volgograd, Mamayev Kurgan" /><button type="button" onclick="geocode();">Search</button><button type="button" onclick="searchWithoutGmap();">Search witout GMap</button>  
<div id="map"></div>  
<div id="output"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#map {  
    width: 400px;  
    height: 300px;  
}
```

**JS**

```
var map;
var marker;
var geocoder;
$( function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map( $( "div#map" )[ 0 ], {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 48.7, 44.516 ),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    } );
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
} );
function geocode() {
    var address = $( "input#address" ).val();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function ( results, status ) {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            // all founded results
            console.log( results );
            // go to first result
            map.panTo( results[ 0 ].geometry.location );
            // and show or replace marker
            if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition( results[ 0 ].geometry.location );
            } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                    position: results[ 0 ].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                } );
            }
            // zoom
            zoomToPan(16);
        } else if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS ) {
            alert( "Zero results." );
        }
    } );
}
function zoomToPan( level_to ) {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if ( level_to != zoom ) {
        setTimeout( function( current_level_to, current_zoom ){
            return function(){
                if ( current_level_to < current_zoom ) {
                    map.setZoom( current_zoom - 1 );
                    zoomToPan( current_level_to );
                } else {
                    map.setZoom( current_zoom + 1 );
                    zoomToPan( current_level_to );
                }
            }
        }( level_to, zoom ), 80 );
    }
}
function searchWithoutGmap() {
    var address = $( "input#address" ).val();
    var format = "json";// xml
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/" + format + "?" + "sensor=false&address=" + address;
    $.ajax( {
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            $( "div#output" ).html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: what if I need to displayed different addresses?

Comment: can you put in the jsfiddle?

Comment: is your code doesnt need the google api? I mean, it directs into google maps website?

Comment: @user3818821 sure needs. See `External Resources` section on jsFiddle, there is [google maps api js file](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js) included.

Comment: Ok. But it is possible to directly go to maps.google.com site without using or creating new google maps, when the user input an address from another website?

Comment: @user3818821 sure! See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru#GeocodingRequests) link, and I'm update answer.

Comment: when I put the value or the string of the home address in this line var address = $( "input#address" ).val(); it is directly go to maps.google.com and display already the home address?

Comment: @user3818821 no. I see, that you don't understand javascript. In `function geocode()` (or in `function searchWithoutGmap()` if you want use it without gmap js file) sends request to the google server and shows response.

Comment: I see, but you use the google api and its not directly go to google map website when I input an address, instead you created a improvise a google map.

Comment: @user3818821 I'l show you a different ways: with javascript google maps API and without it, look at `function searchWithoutGmap()` on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/JkLSC/4/) - it's ajax request on google maps site. Or what you want?